# Writing Permission to linux apache on windows folder

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008, apache-2.2, samba

We have a ubuntu 10.04 with apache 2 and samba. We set apache2 /var/www/ to be on a Windows Directory over the network using samba. It's all working but I can't seem to find a way to give writing permission on this directory. I've tried both on linux and windows. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Windows are you using and have you looked at NTLM as the cause?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc960646.aspx

I've had issues on Windows Vista and 7 when trying to authenticate with Samba, I had to change the windows registry key “HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\LMCompatibilityLevel” to “1”.

What do your logs tell you?

Comment: It's a Windows Server 2008. I don't really know what a NTLM is. But I can see the directory, it's readable but i need to change the permission to writeable.

Comment: In the samba configuration file for that path you need to add writable = yes

Answer (score 0):

Have you been running SWAT already? It's a graphical front-end for Samba, using a web interface so it shows up on http:localhost/901 on the Ubuntu-machine.

Manually editing samba-configuration files and setting permissions may be daunting, but with SWAT it's really easy.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Swat